# how dose @property and @synthesize works?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Property Declaration and Automatic Backing Storage Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238009/property-declaration-and-automatic-backing-storage-allocation)

I know the basic functions of @property and @synthesize directives, but recently I found a sample code: [image]

There's not any class member variables in TTDownloader, but it works perfect.

```
TTDownloader *dl = [[TTDownloader alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d %@", dl.aaa, dl.bbb); // result: 0 (null)
dl.aaa = 101;
dl.bbb = [NSNumber numberWithInt:201];
NSLog(@"%d %@", dl.aaa, dl.bbb); // result: 101 201
```

My questions are listed below:

1. Where is aaa and bbb? I don't even have a place to hold these data. TTDownloader is empty (except some variables and functions derived from NSObject).
2. Did I miss some great features of Objective C? Are they described in Obj-C Programming Guide, I just read part of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Property Declaration and Automatic Backing Storage Allocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238009/) and [Must every ivar really be property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031230/) and [What's the purpose of an ivar when a property exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336922/) and [Why don't I need an ivar for this property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837584) and [What is the difference between ivar and property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299487/) and [Defining ivar and property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854901/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the modern runtime on all platforms except 32 bit OS X, when you synthesize a property, if the instance variable has not been declared, it will be created automatically. so

1. aaa and bbb are properties i.e. each  is a pair of accessor methods which are synthesized and use the instance variables _aaa and _bbb respectively.
2. Yes, see above.